# Cannot open Steam on Debian system

Tags: debian

So I installed Steam on my Debian-based Linux machine. When I try to open it, it says:

> You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6

Can anyone give me the command to install it, or explain why this is happening?

I've tried some commands to install the software but they never work or it says that it public key isn't available and it couldn't fetch the signatures. I'm not a coder or anything so I need some expert advice.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Super User. Can you please give some more detail about your setup and what you have tried so far? For instance, which version of Debian are you using? What commands did you try, and what console output did those commands give?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
# apt install libc6
```

to install the [libc6](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libc6) package that the error message you are getting indicates you are missing. The error message is letting you know that the software you are trying to run (Steam, in this case) requires another package (libc6, in this case) in order to run. `apt` will usually handle these dependencies for you, but in your case, it appears it didn't

We can't really tell you for certain why this package wasn't automatically installed with Steam without more information on how you installed Steam.